# How to customize leaflet labels? and when I change the opacity, it changes opacity of the fonts as well

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

```
let myIcon = L.icon({
iconUrl: 'images/Province_Center.png',
iconSize: [9.2, 9],
});

L.marker([34.537205, 69.191150],{icon:myIcon}).bindTooltip("Kabul",{permanent: true, direction: 
'right'}).addTo(map),
L.marker([34.349708, 62.203600],{icon:myIcon}).bindTooltip("Herat",{permanent: true, direction: 
'right'}).addTo(map),
L.marker([34.427256, 70.457220],{icon:myIcon}).bindTooltip("Nangarhar",{permanent: true, direction: 
'right'}).addTo(map),
L.marker([36.708842, 67.110785],{icon:myIcon}).bindTooltip("Balk",{permanent: true, direction: 
'right'}).addTo(map),
```

I want to change the font color, background color and the label position.

Comment: your question doesn't seem to show what you already tried ("when I change the opacity, it changes the opacity of the font as well"). Could you add that? It will make it easier to help you. Also, what do you mean by label? Do you mean the tooltip?

Comment: Here is my CSS and when I change the opacity to zero, it change the font opacity as well. I only want the label to be displayed,  not the background or the tooltip window.

.leaflet-tooltip-pane {
    opacity: 0.8;
    color:red;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can add html to the tooltip instead of plain text:

```
L.marker([34.537205, 69.191150]).bindTooltip("<span style='font-size: 40px'>Kabul</span>",{permanent: true, direction: 'right'}).addTo(map);
```

Also you can add your own css style to the tooltip:

```
.leaflet-tooltip {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: This helps, but again I don't want any background or label frame. just a plain text/label without window/frame. Thanks!